# I want to add the following code into a table and limit amount of entries

Tags: mysql

I have the following code on a .php page and I want to display it inside a table and only show the last 10 entries

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dispenses";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<br> Amount: " . $row["amount"] . " - Time Dispensed: ". $row["dispensed"] . "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the number of results with `LIMIT`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dispenses LIMIT 10";
```

You can choose an offset as well. Check [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) for more.

***p.s.***: so in order to get last `x` entries using order by `y` use:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM dispenses ".
        "ORDER BY y DESC LIMIT 10) AS intermediate ORDER by y ASC";
```

Check [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d18e/1) to see how it works. I select the last three records based on id or insert date. I forgot to define an alias in the statement above. This is fixed now. Hope it helps ....

Comment: I believe that would return FIRST 10 entries, not LAST 10 as requested by OP

Comment: Yes, but it can simply  used to achieve the result using the right order. But that depends on what is "last"

Comment: sorry last is suppose to mean most recent

Comment: @dubster: see update above; if you have a date or time stamp column (lets call it `y`) you can use the code above.

Comment: @Trinimon once I paste the below code nothing comes up anymore as a result on my webpage

$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM dispenses ORDER BY y DESC LIMIT 10) ORDER by y ASC";

here is the webpage I am trying to display it on http://paycoinfaucet.cf/feedback

Comment: @dubster: you need something to identify what your last entries are. This might be an insert date or an auto incremented id. `y` was meant to be a place holder for that kind of column. I'll add an SQL example ...

Comment: Thanks for the help I got it figured out

$sql = "SELECT * FROM dispenses ORDER BY dispensed DESC LIMIT 10";

Comment: @dubster: that's of course possible as well - it just results in a reversed order. But as you are using the result set in PHP, it probably doesn't matter :D

Answer (score 1):

You could store all the results in an array and subsequently display only last 10 elements of that array.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $results[] = $row;
}

for($i = count($results)-10; $i < count($results); $i++){
    echo "<br> Amount: " . $results[$i]["amount"] . " - Time Dispensed: ". $results[$i]["dispensed"] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: +1 This can definitely work for small tables, but might be dangerous for large tables, because you fetch all records first